# Pandas diffing rows in one group against rows of the previous group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

How to determine the difference between rows in `col X` but between groups, rather than within groups.  So the `diff` value within groups should be `ffill`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({   
        'Time' : [1,1,2,2,3,3],                              
        'X' : [1,1,3,3,6,6],
        'Y' : [1,1,1,1,2,2],
    })

df['X'] = df['X'].diff()

df['X'] = df.groupby('Time')['X'].diff()
```

Intended Output:

```
   Time  X  Y
0     1  0  1
1     1  0  1
2     2  2  1
3     2  2  1
4     3  3  2
5     3  3  2
```

Comment: Are all values inside a group equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If values inside a group are equal (but the number of rows per group are not), you can do this by subtracting all rows in a group with the value of the previous group.

```
df['X'] - df['Time'].map(df.groupby('Time')['X'].max().shift()).fillna(df['X'])

0    0.0
1    0.0
2    2.0
3    2.0
4    3.0
5    3.0
dtype: float64
```

---

**Details**
The first piece is to find the unique values in each group (I use `max()`, but you can just as well use `unique()` or `first()`):

```
df.groupby('Time')['X'].max()

Time
1    1
2    3
3    6
Name: X, dtype: int64
```

Next, shift them down:

```
_.shift()

Time
1    NaN
2    1.0
3    3.0
Name: X, dtype: float64
```

Map it back to "Time" (the grouper):

```
df['Time'].map(_)

0    NaN
1    NaN
2    1.0
3    1.0
4    3.0
5    3.0
Name: Time, dtype: float64
```

Fill the first group of NaNs with "X":

```
_.fillna(df['X'])

0    1.0
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    1.0
4    3.0
5    3.0
Name: Time, dtype: float64
```

Now you have your RHS. Just subtract this from "X" and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed rows for each group you can do

```py
>>> df.X = df.X.diff(periods=2).fillna(0)    # assumes all groups have two rows
>>> df
   Time    X  Y
0     1  0.0  1
1     1  0.0  1
2     2  2.0  1
3     2  2.0  1
4     3  3.0  2
5     3  3.0  2
```